# When Loading html file with require.js error with extension

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have file

**reg.html**

```
<label>Name:</label>
```

in require.config :

```
requirejs.config({

 paths: {
 reg:"/templates/reg.html"
}

})
```

When i try load template :

```
define('ng_start',["angular","jquery","reg"],function(An,$,template){
....
})
```

**GET /templates/registry.html.js?bust=1417489939824228.12310815788805 
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: registry
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror**

How deleted js extension from registry.html.js ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to state that your "reg" module is to be loaded as text and not as a JavaScript module.  See the following for details:

https://github.com/requirejs/text

Your specific code should read:

```
define('ng_start',["angular","jquery","text!reg"],function(An,$,template){
....
})
```

**note**: the addition of `text!` in the module definition requirements for `reg`.